# Average of closely repeating range in a list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Need to find average of maximum closely repeating range of concentrated values in the list of values.

Say two list of floats,

```
case1:{2.43,9.23,10,24,1.0,2.87,7.45,5.1,8.56,2.34,2.65}

case2:{9.23,10,8.21,1.0,2.34,6.43,4.65,7.45,5.1,3.56,2.31}
```

Output for case1: average of(1.0,2.34,2.43,2.65,2.87) - because range of 1.0,2.34,2.43,2.65,2.87 is close(difference of values of sorted elements are minimum) but rest(9.23, 10, 24, 7.45,8.56) are either not so close as the earlier range or not the maximum range(9.23, 10, 7.45,8.56 - 4 elements)

Output for case2:0 or default value - if you sort the list and take differences of consecutive elements,the diff would be very similar. So no cluster as such.

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me. It sounds like you’re looking for clusters of numbers close to each other? What if there’s more than one such cluster? What if there are two clusters close to each other, is that one cluster or two?

Comment: @Tom: In case of multiple clusters, result can be extrapolated based on demand. I mean as per need. I can choose either the maximum or minimum valued cluster. Let us now concentrate assuming only one cluster as per the given dataset.

Comment: Still very unclear. If you don't post the algorithm as RV asked, this will probably be closed.

Comment: @Ryan: I am not sure if any readily available algo is there of this kind, have to write my own. It seems close to finding a "mode" of a list, although not exactly.

Comment: edited the original post. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: we can define closeness range with a delta. In that case delta can be maximum accepted value to be in a range, difference value anything more than delta wont fall in that cluster.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

- only one cloud (or the *best*);
- a cloud is in a range R (max - min of datas <= R)

**Brute force solution 1:**

- put all datas in a Collection, and sort;
- iterate through every element Ax
- go the the right to find all elements in the range Ax+R
- ? keep that information: Ax (or element of indice x) => n elements
- keep also the max of this n (with this x)

At end, you will have every possible clouds, and the one with the most elements.
- then you take this one, and calculate the mean.

Many ways to improve that (like re-using precedent cloud/sum/mean when you go to right);

It is about O(n) for the second part. You have to add the cost of sorting.